# Android Create a class into separate file without new mClass() ...?

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I'm trying to handle classes in a simple way, but I can't achieve it...

so far... I created a separateClass.java, with it's constructor and method, but in the Main.java, I call a method of separateClass.java in this way...

```
// Current way...
separateClass sp = new separateClass(myPathString);
String newPath = sp.myMethod();

// The way I would like...
String newPath = myMethod(myPathString);

// ADDED AFTER RESPONSE...
// This way helps me when I have more classes (.javas)
String newThig = separateClass.myMethod(myPathString);
String anotherThing = myOtherLibrary.methodForSomeThing(someString);
String numCheck = myCalculations.terrain(altitude, latitude);

// Note: The static way is just recomended with simples processes that don't
// need many objects or constructors.
// so far this is what I understand.
```

It is possible?, how can I do that?
I appreciate some ideas!  :)

**Edited...**

```
public class separateClass{

    /* Not needed if static (for novices)
    String myPathString;

    public Imagen_DirectorioGestor(String myPathString) {
        this.myPathString= myPathString;
    }
    */

    public static String myMethod(String myPathString){
        File file = new File(myPathString);
        newPath = ...;
        return newPath;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the method inside of SeparateClass static:

```
public static String myMethod(String path) {
    ...
}
```

Then from your activity call the myMethod like this:

```
SeparateClass.myMethod(myPathString);
```

**If that's not enough** you can import the method in your MainActivity:

```
import static com.mypackage.SeparateClass.myMethod;
```

And then you can use the method without any class reference:

```
myMethod();
```

Comment: Your first example works!, but I have questions... I have a constructor that recieve a string value, and now my method recieve a string too... its necessary the construcctor with the static method?

Comment: @arickdev Your method can set a static field inside of your class and then your constructor can be receive no arguments.

Comment: Why the method should be static?, I read about that but its dificult to me undertand well the static thing! :(

Comment: @arickdev If you want to access a method inside of a class without first instantiating (*new Class()*) that class, then the method must be static.

Comment: ok, I understand, but... I still need the constructor?, there is something that I need to correct in my code?

Comment: @arickdev If you will never instantiate that specific class of course it doesn't need a constructor. Please read more about Object Oriented Programming. StackOverflow is ment for specific questions, one question at a time :)

Comment: 're right ... sorry ... I read a lot but ... there are many things in java php ... in structured had not seen, to me this is crazy xD (and I speak spanish): P

Comment: the first example runs but second gives me an error of host... but I think that problem is more easy, thank you very much!, your example is helpful!

Comment: @arickdev the 2nd example requires you to change the com.mypackage to your package.

Comment: the code did his job, but in the end, just failed on logcat, so I went to Project -> Clean ... and it worked without errors this time. thank you very much again!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it if **Main** class extends **SeparateClass** and your method is not private.

```
public class SeparateClass {
    public   void myMethod() {


    }
}

public class Main extends SeparateClass{

    public  void testMethod() {
       myMethod();

   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks!, but, extend the main class... i don't know... I would like have many separate classes, and to extend all of them... it's too much code in the class name... but thanks! :)

Comment: You asked about the possibility so I refer simplest way :-)

Comment: yes... I used that way before... it work!, in this case I need a diferent way... thanks any way! :)